# Stylesheet.create returns objects not numbers

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I did a simple test on my local setup, with RN 0.62.2:

```
const styles = Stylesheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
});

console.log(styles);
```

Given that in theory Stylesheet is caching the style, I expected a log like this:

```
{
  container: 120
}
```

But actually it returns the object:

```
{
  container: { flex: 1 }
}
```

Then I tried the same with an expo app (https://snack.expo.io/@agustito37/4a556c) with the same version of RN, and the result was the expected:

```
{
  container: 120
}
```

So I am a little confused, some people argue that caching was removed ([What is the point of StyleSheet.create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886020/what-is-the-point-of-stylesheet-create)); but given expo is returning the identifier I am not sure, is Stylesheet.create working properly or not?
Why do I have different results with expo? Could it be that expo has an older version of Stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because **react-native-web** will register style objects as atomic css classes when you use `StyleSheet.create`. So it probably is returning an id of what was registered back. If you don't route your style object through `StyleSheet.create`, you will get inline styles rendered. I discovered this while using UI Kitten with expo/react-native-web and took screenshots of the different css/styles that get generated for each approach:

https://github.com/akveo/react-native-ui-kitten/issues/1266

I think at some point it used to work similarly on **react native** with intention of optimizing trips across bridge, but apparently that is no longer the case based on the link you included. Interesting!